# SQLCipher v3.2.0 can't open databases created with SQLCipher v2.1.1

Tags: windows, dll, sqlcipher

I've compiled SQLCipher v3.2.0 using the SQLCipher GIT repository, mingw32 and this [how-to](http://www.jerryrw.com/howtocompile.php).
I did succeded to get a working sqlite3.dll that can create crypted and uncrypted databases.

But when I try to open encrypted databases that were created with SQLCipher v2.1.1, it fails to open the databases. I also tried to open the databases created with SQLCipher v3.2.0 using SQLCipher v2.1.1 and it fails too.

I guess the issue is about the default cipher algorithm used by SQLCipher v3.2.0 and the one used by SQLCipher v2.1.1.

Using the source files available on the GIT repository, I checked the default cipher algorithm that was used with SQLCipher v2.1.1 which was AES-256-CBC using a key of 64 (byte/bit). SQLCipher v3.2.0 seems to use the same default algorithm.

SQLCipher v2.1.1 was a static version bought on [zetetic.net](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher) two years ago.

Is there a way to check with what algorithm the databases were encrypted ? I guess no.

Do you guys think it a cipher algorithm selection issue ? or something else ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3.x version of SQLCipher can operate on a 2.x database, however the key derivation length was increased from 4,000 to 64,000 which is likely why you are seeing a problem.  You can perform a one time upgrade of the 2.x database file by issuing the following command after you have keyed the database:

`PRAGMA cipher_migrate;`

An alternative would be to adjust the `kdf_iter` value down to 4000.  More information regarding these options is available on the [blog post](https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2013/11/11/sqlcipher-300-release.html) covering the 3.0.0 release.

Comment: I'll check this out. I guess using a bigger key derivation length is nice to get a stronger encryption ?

Comment: Using a larger iteration length means that it takes a longer period of time to compute the key based on the provided password, this is particularly beneficial when it comes to slowing down brute force attacks.